# PHP array_key_exists with numeric keys

Tags: arrays, key, exists

I load an array in PHP using an index number, not an alphanumeric key. The array can contain anywhere from 0 to 100 entries depending on the data. The array is loaded sequentially from 0-100.

However, in order to perform desired processing there must be at minimum 13 entries in the array. If there aren't 13 entries, some other processing occurs.

SO, is this the correct format to use to see if the 13th array item has a value....or does it need single quotes around the 12?

```
If ( !array_key_exists(12,$array) ) {
.........
}
```

I'm also assuming that using isset will give me an error if $array[12] hasn't been created and given a value......i.e:

```
If ( !isset($array[12]) ) {
..........
}
```

Edit: I WAS using just this before, and not sure under what conditions it would be true/false.

```
If ( !$array[12] ) {
...........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using php's empty() function to test if the variable exists.

```
if ( empty($array[12] ) {
.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you!.....But there's either gonna be some value in $array[12] or it won't even exist. It will never exist and be empty/null/whatever..

Will empty() return false if an array item doesn't exist?......z

Comment: I mean will empty($array{12]) return True if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I believe that empty() will indeed return True if an array item does not exist.

Comment: Any benefit to using empty() over isset() ?